# What is this sheathing/ board?

Tags: drywall, paint, asbestos, sheathing, board

Can anyone tell me what this is please? My dad kept assuring me it was just "fluff board" with white paint, and nothing to worry about (i.e. not asbestos). Can anyone corroborate that? It's a green board that's quite soft and tears easily into pieces. I was worried the "paint" looked a bit textured but I think it's just the board underneath giving that effect. Google doesn't show anything relevant when I search fluff board! I've included a photo of where it's been torn off from too just for reference.

Thanks in advance

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

[image: image3]

[image: image4]

Comment: I don't think it's asbestos.  It looks like a cement board, with possibly cellulose fibers in it.

If you can date by a stamp on it or if your Dad can remember when he bought it, and if asbestos is banned in your country then you could be more certain.

But it looks like you have already removed it.  To be safe, use gloves and a good quality mask, spray water on it and gently take it out.

To be 100% sure, call the professionals.

Comment: Remember there can be asbestos in the board, or in plaster/mud on top of the board, or in any insulation or lagging behind the board.

Answer (score 6):

### It's Homasote®

The way it tears and the surface texture are diagnostic.

Celluose - paper fiber.

Comment: Link to website that has information on Homasote fiber board and identification of Homasote https://inspectapedia.com/interiors/Homasote-History-Products-Composition.php

Comment: Or there's straight from the horse's mouth: http://www.homasote.com

Comment: Still - unlikely to be be pure homasote in the UK

Answer (score 4):

If you want absolute confirmation that it doesn't contain asbestos, there are reasonably-priced labs which can check a sample for you.

Comment: Absolutely, if the makeup of the wall suggests a 1970s build/redo or prior, I would certainly have it tested. I am only familiar with Homasote coming in 1/2" thick sheets. Of course, there is no reason why it could not be made thinner, it is just I have never seen it in the supply stores I frequented over time.

Comment: I see no indication that it's not 1/2" here...

Comment: This is the only safe answer - I remember seeing an old timer builder test a sample **by taste** and assert it had no asbestos....   and he was incorrect according to the lab result.